# Warum hat das Deutsche so viele zusammengesetzte Wörter?

Tags: compound

Es ist ja so, dass das Deutsche zusammengesetzte Wörter (Autobahn, Fahrgemeinschaft, Klingelschild) hat, andere Sprachen aber üblicherweise nicht. Gibt es einen historischen oder sonstigen Grund, wieso die deutsche Sprache hier eine Ausnahme bildet?

Comment: Streng genommen ist Deutsch keine echte Ausnahme: Niederländisch hat auch viele.

Comment: Und wenn wir nach Leerzeichen zwischen Wörtern gehen, ist ein ganzes chinesisches Buch ein "Wort". Aber Spaß beiseite: [What determines how noun compounds are formed in a language?](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/1116/what-determines-how-noun-compounds-are-formed-in-a-language)

Comment: @c.p. Würde zu meiner Antwort passen ;)

Comment: Fast alle Sprachen bilden Komposita, nur die Regeln zur Schreibweise unterscheiden sich (viele Sprachen haben im übrigen *gar keine* Schriftform). Das Deutsche ist wegen seiner Komposita nicht ungewöhnlicher als wegen der Großschreibung für Nomen: beide betreffen nur die Schriftform und nicht die grundlegende Funktionsweise.

Comment: Wie groß ist der Unterschied zwischen garden plant und Gartenpflanze?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Ich möchte dem »andere Sprachen üblicherweise nicht« aufs schärfste widersprechen. Die Frage ist nur, *wie* andere Sprachen ihre zusammengesetzten Wörter bilden. Dabei gibt es mehrere Techniken:

- Analog dem Deutschen das Aneinanderheften verschiedener Fragmente zu einem ganzen Wort
  Auch: Finnisch (ammatti + korkea + koulu = ammattikorkeakoulu)

  - gegebenenfalls auch mit Bindestrichen:
    English, Französisch (vire + lingue = vire-lingue)
- Das Zusammensetzen von Wörtern mit Bindepartikeln.
  Beispiel: Französisch (pomme + terre = pomme de terre)
- Das Hintereinanderschreiben von scheinbar zusammenhanglosen Wörtern, um eine neue Bedeutung zu erzeugen.
  Beispiel: Englisch (swimming + pool = swimming pool)

Die meisten Sprachen, wenn nicht alle, verwenden eine Kombination verschiedener Techniken, wobei manche jeweils beliebter oder unbeliebter sind. Im Deutschen sind Bindestrichkombinationen zum Beispiel extrem unbeliebt.

Wahrscheinlich ist diese Frage in der Annahme entstanden, dass das Englische viel weniger Komposita habe als das Deutsche. Dem ist aber nicht wirklich so, die meisten englischen Komposita werden einfach mit Leerzeichen geschrieben: *cat flap, spring green, go home, wheat flour, cell wall, …*

Natürlich hat das Deutsche ein paar Freiheiten, die Englisch nicht hat: Die berühmte Donaudampfschifffahrtsgesellschaftskapitänsmütze muss man im Englischen in einer Kombination aus der zweiten und dritten Methode zusammenbauen.

Andererseits ist das Deutsche auch noch nicht das Ende der Fahnenstange: Im Finnischen kann man beispielsweise ein Kompositum bauen, das »ein Komplex, weil man nicht in Prag war« bedeutet: *Prahassakäymättömyyskompleksi*.

---

Dass hier Finnisch, Englisch und Französisch sich so unterschiedlich verhalten, würde ich am ehesten den zugehörigen Sprachfamilien unterstellen; denn das wenige Italienisch, das ich kann, scheint dem Französischen näher zu sein, und das bisschen Schwedisch, das ich verstehe, scheint dem Deutschen zumindest ähnlich in seiner Komposita-Bildungsfähigkeit zu sein. Aber *diese* Teilfrage wäre wohl auf dem Linguistics-Stack-Exchange besser aufgehoben.

Comment: Nebenbei bemerkt hat auch Englisch das eine oder andere "echte" zusammengesetzte Wort. http://www.manythings.org/vocabulary/lists/a/words.php?f=compound_words   nach welchen Regeln da vorgegangen wird ist eine interessante Frage.

Comment: @Emanuel Stimmt. Ich hab versucht, es klarer zu machen, dass in allen Sprachen alle Kombinationen vorkommen *können* aber manche bevorzugt sind. Nebenbei kann das Französisch natürlich auch: *aéroport, bonheur, …*

Comment: Alles völlig richtig. Die erste und dritte Methode unterscheiden sich allerdings nur oberflächlich - durch die Rechtschreibung. Sie sind in vielen Sprachfamilien wie den germanischen und den finno-ugrischen Sprachen Standard. Die zweite Methode ist der Standard in den romanischen Sprachen. Als Extrembeispiel für die erste Methode wird häufig das türkische **Wort** für "Ich gehöre zu denen, die nicht europäisiert werden können" genannt.

Comment: @HansAdler Wow, das ist ja noch weitgehender als mein »Komplex, weil ich nicht in Prag war« =O Auch die zweite Methode unterscheidet sich meines Erachtens nur oberflächlich von den anderen beiden; siehe das Fugen-s im Deutschen, das in manchen Fällen (fälschlicherweise?) als erstarrtes Genitiv-s gedeutet werden kann – ähnlich einem Partikel.

Comment: @Hans Adler, was ist eigentlich das türkische Wort für "ich gehöre zu denen,die nicht..."? Kannst du bitte den Satz bisschen weiter klar machen?

Comment: Ich kann kein Türkisch, aber "you are one of those who cannot be Europeanized" wird in der Encyclopedia of Linguistics (Dearborn) so wiedergegeben: "avrupalılaştırılamıyanlardansınız". Der Anfang dieser Zusammensetzung ist für uns noch leicht nachzuvollziehen. Alles geht ähnlich wie im Deutschen, aber ohne Rückgriff auf fremde (z.B. lateinische) Konstruktionen: *Avrupa* = Europa; *avrupalı* = europäisch; *avrupalılaş* = europäisch werden; *avrupalılaştır* = europäisieren (wörtlich: europäisch werden machen); *avrupalılaştırıl* = europäisiert werden.

Comment: *avrupalılaştırılamı* = nicht europäisiert werden können; *avrupalılaştırılamıyan* = nicht europäisiert werden könnend/Könnender (Partizip); *avrupalılaştırılamıyanlar* = nicht europäisiert werden Könnende (Plural); *avrupalılaştırılamıyanlardan* = von [den] nicht europäisiert werden Könnenden (Ablativ). Zum Abschluss kommt dann noch die Personalendung für die zweite Person Plural, die aus dem ganzen Gebilde einen Satz macht.

Comment: Zu jedem einzelnen Schritt gibt es im Deutschen vergleichbare Endungen, die ganz ähnlich funktionieren. Fremd ist nur die Regelmäßigkeit und Konsequenz mit der das passiert und die Möglichkeit, mit Personalendungen aus deklinierten Substantiven Sätze zu machen.

Answer (score 8):

Die Behauptung in der Frage ist falsch. Es gibt viele Sprachen mit solchen zusammengesetzten Wörtern, z. B. Schwedisch:

- farmor
- östat
- skattemyndigheten
- hastighetsgräns
- sannolikhetsteori.

Das gleiche gilt für Norwegisch. Und für Dänisch.

Comment: Gute Beispiele, vor allem, weil ich nun vermittels des Schwedischen die Zusammensetzung von „wahrscheinlich“ verstanden habe ;) Es sind sich dort also die germanischen Sprachen außer Englisch ähnlich. Es könnte natürlich immer noch eine Eigenart nur ihrer sein.

Comment: Schwedisch ist immer nützlich! Wie es bei anderen Sprachgruppen aussieht, müßte man prüfen. Z. B. mal die indischen oder nordamerikanischen durchgehen. Da bin ich aber kein Experte.

Comment: Zumindest kenne ich vom Japanischen die Variante Zusammenschreiben auch – es ist aber nicht so leicht ersichtlich, ob 子猫 nun *koneko* oder *ko neko* geschrieben werden soll, denn gleichzeitig kennt das Japanische keine Zwischenräume zwischen Wörtern … so oder so ist es die Kombination aus 子 (*ko* = Kind) und 猫 (*neko* = Katze).

Comment: Gestern habe ich gelernt, daß es bei Sanskrit und den daraus abgeleiteten indischen Sprachen genauso geht. Beispiel: Himalaja = Haus des Schnees.